# Blinking cursor after checking /dev/sda2 on boot

Tags: boot, drive, disk-check

A few weeks ago, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Acer C720 (Intel Celeron 2955U, 2GB LPDDR3 RAM). (I used MrChromebox UEFI firmware). No problems, works OK, a bit slow, and some internal GTK errors that might be from the ram (a few years ago, I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on an HP DC7900 which also sometimes gave me internal errors).

The Problem:

Yesterday, I was torrenting a file. I had to force restart in the middle of torrenting because
the laptop froze. Then, turning it on, showed the Ubuntu splash screen. Then, it was checking /dev/sda2 and recovering journal. Then it showed a blinking cursor and got stuck on it. Also, I tried aceessing the terminal using keyboard shortcuts but they don't work. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have self answered my question by reinstalling Ubuntu. There might be answers in the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange.

Comment: The link is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612578/blinking-cursor-after-checking-dev-sda2-on-boot-in-ubuntu